# How to perform search using OpenIE

Tags: nlp, opennlp, information-extraction

I downloaded the OpenIE by UWashington. The binary accepts a sentence and output the tags. However on their website http://openie.cs.washington.edu/ they demonstrate the search functions. You could search "person" and "location" and get results like "live in", "work in", etc. However their github website doesn't tell you how to do this. How could I do this and supply my own data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use search software (e.g. elasticsearch, Whoosh) to build an index on the subject-predicate-object tuples extracted from your data. For example, if you use elasticsearch, you would need to iterate over all the OpenIE output and create a request like this for each tuple:

`curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/spos/spo/' -d '{
    "subject" : "martians",
    "predicate" : "live in",
    "object" : "the moon"
}'`

Once the index is built you can do searches and aggregations on any combination of subject, predicate and object:

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/spos/_search?q=predicate:live in AND object:the moon'`

Comment: You mean I have to extract the triplet data from OpenIE first? I guess they have already have published the dataset in http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/ However this database was created more than 2 years ago. Is there any newer versions for download?